# BeautifulSoup4 Extracting {{ stat.displayValue }} and not the actual Value. Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am simply trying to extract 1 data point but I am afraid I am doing something incorrectly.  I am trying to print our "**0.93**" instead of `{{ stat.displayValue }}`   Help is much appreciated :)

Code from the website:

```
<div class="trn-stats">
        <div class="trn-stat">
            <span class="name">KD</span>
            <span class="value">0.93</span>
```

My code after making `r = requests.get("").text` etc:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
PvP = soup.find('div', class_='gt-pvp-casual')
stats = PvP.find('div', class_='trn-stats')
value = stats.find('span', class_='value')

print(value)
```

It prints:

```
<span class="value">{{ stat.displayValue }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you are getting could imply that there is client-side JavaScript involved, e.g. [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02).

The JavaScript is not being executed when you are running your script, thus the expression `{{ stat.displayValue }}` is not being evaluated.

There are many ways to peel that particular apple, one would be using [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium).